# Orthonormal Basis for $L^2(E)$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose $\{\varphi_n\}$ is orthonormal basis of $L^2(E)$. Then for every $f\in L^2(E)$ we have
\begin{equation*}
f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle f,\varphi_n\rangle\varphi_n,
\end{equation*}
with this series absolutely convergent, so $\left\vert\langle f,\varphi_n\rangle\right\vert=0$ as $n\to\infty.$ Then
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E f(x)\overline{\varphi_n(x)}dx=0.
\end{equation*}
Does this imply 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E f(x)\varphi_n(x)dx=0?
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, apply the previous line to $\overline {f}$ and the take the conjugate.

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit? Thanks

Comment: @aloevera The complex conjugate of $\int \overline {f} \, \overline {\phi_n} dx$ is same as $\int f \phi_n dx$.